# xsl to move node under precibling parent based on matching of parent attribute

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to handle a xml converted from a pdf to another xml file in some format. First I want to move / group some text / node together based on the geometry of the text but failed to do so. The following is my input & what I wanted:

input xml:

```
<Pages>
    <Page>
        <PAGENUMBER>1</PAGENUMBER>
        <Box llx="59.40" lly="560.64" urx="68.58" ury="571.68">
            <Text>5.</Text>
        </Box>
        <Box llx="81.84" lly="560.64" urx="194.39" ury="571.68">
           <Text>Equipment list</Text>
        </Box>
        <Box llx="257.40" lly="560.64" urx="265.36" ury="571.68">
            <Text>C</Text>
        </Box>
        <Box llx="315.84" lly="535.32" urx="325.63" ury="546.36">
            <Text>a)</Text>
        </Box>
    </Page>
    <Page>
         same structure as above...
    </Page>
</Pages>
```

Output xml:

```
<Pages>
    <Page>
        <PAGENUMBER>1</PAGENUMBER>
        <Box llx="59.40" lly="560.64" urx="68.58" ury="571.68">
            <Text>5. Equipment list C</Text>
        </Box>
        <Box llx="315.84" lly="535.32" urx="325.63" ury="546.36">
            <Text>a)</Text>
        </Box>
    </Page>
    <Page>
         same structure as above...
    </Page>
</Pages>
```

What i have:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name = "identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>          
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Box">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@ury = following-sibling::Box/@ury">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Box/Text"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

1.It doesn't copy the wanted nodes 2. i don't know how to exclude the following nodes. I hope someone can help me on this. Many thanks in advance.

I tried the following to exclude the duplicates but it doesn't copy what i want anyways:

```
<xsl:template match="Box[@ury !=  preceding-sibling::Box/@ury]/Text">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of [muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) in which you need to group the nodes based on certain common criteria and process them to provide an output.

Based on the version of XSLT being used, the solution differs for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0

**XSLT 1.0**

Version 1.0 uses a `<xsl:key>` to group the elements based on common criteria. In this case, the grouping is being done based on the value of attribute `@ury` so we define a key

```
<xsl:key name="groupingKey" match="Box" use="@ury" />
```

Using this key, the templates are grouped together for processing.

```
<xsl:template match="Box[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groupingKey', @ury)[1])]">
```

Finally within the grouped elements, a loop is run over the `<Text>` elements to concatenate its values.

```
<Text>
    <xsl:variable name="fullText">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('groupingKey', @ury)/Text">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($fullText)" />
</Text>
```

Below is the complete XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="groupingKey" match="Box" use="@ury" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Box[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groupingKey', @ury)[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <Text>
                <xsl:variable name="fullText">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('groupingKey', @ury)/Text">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($fullText)" />
            </Text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Box" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

Version 2.0 is advanced and provides a simpler approach as compared to XSLT 1.0. The `<xsl:for-each-group>` and `group-by` feature can be used to group the elements together.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Box" group-by="@ury">
```

Below is the complete XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Page">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PAGENUMBER" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Box" group-by="@ury">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                    <Text>
                        <xsl:variable name="fullText">
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/Text">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')" />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($fullText)" />
                    </Text>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both the XSLT provide the required output

```
<Pages>
    <Page>
        <PAGENUMBER>1</PAGENUMBER>
        <Box llx="59.40" lly="560.64" urx="68.58" ury="571.68">
            <Text>5. Equipment list C</Text>
        </Box>
        <Box llx="315.84" lly="535.32" urx="325.63" ury="546.36">
            <Text>a)</Text>
        </Box>
    </Page>
</Pages>
```

Comment: Wow it works perfect. I was thinking to use java to do it yesterday but now i don't need that. looks that xsl could do a lot more than what i thought. Well i only have 4 months experience to work on xsl 1.0 and FO and then company decided not doing more xsl & xslt as it is difficult to find a stylesheet developer here in Canada. But to be honest - there is not much position for stylesheet developer either so i stopped learning it. looks like i really should spend more time on it. again Thanks a lot!!

Comment: XSLT is definitely powerful and the newer versions viz. 2.0/3.0 have added lot of features as compared to 1.0. It also provides lot of flexibility and loose coupling when working with XMLs and can, on its own have an architectural layer when integrating with other applications.